# Where can I find a sandbox Vuetify 3 template online with which to create a minimum reproducible example?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm having an issue with Vuetify 3 that I want to ask about on Stack Overflow, but to do that I need to create a minimum reproducible example.  Where can I find a template I can work off?

### What I've tried

- I tried creating my own on codesandbox.io but it's taking a long time to get it working as I don't use sandboxes a lot.
- I tried Googling to find an existing example I could work off but couldn't find one.
- I tried using the ones linked to in the Vuetify documentation but it seems they can't be saved and shared in a modified state. [Update: this is incorrect, as the accepted answer made clear.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [official playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/), which is probably easiest if you want to use SFCs. The content of the playground is encoded into the URL, so you can save it by saving the URL.

Or you can create a snippet using CDN Vue and Vuetify:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
const app = {
  template: `
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  `,
  setup(){
    return {
      
    }
  }
}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh ok I was just mistaken about the official playground not letting you save your changes.  Thank you!

Comment: Oh, right, sorry, I misread that - the content of the playground is encoded into the URL