# How can I import directly from vuetify.min.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to import `createVuetify` from Vuetify 3 in a CodePen and I'm getting the following error:

```
import { createVuetify } from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/3.3.12/vuetify.min.js';
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/3.3.12/vuetify.min.js' does not provide an export named 'createVuetify' (at pen.js?key=pen.js-ee80a9fe-1eb9-15f6-9df6-aba0200e0486:1:10)

What's the correct way to do this?

#### HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-text-field
      :value="{{ testVariable }}"
    ></v-text-field>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
import { createVuetify } from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/3.3.12/vuetify.min.js';
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: createVuetify({
    theme: { defaultTheme: 'light' },
  }),
  data() {
    return {
      testVariable: "asdf"
    }
  },
  methods: {
  }
})
```

Comment: That's not the suggested procedure.  https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/  `createVuetify` is not a standalone function.  It's a member of the `Vuetify` object.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for replying.  That link doesn't seem to explain how to set up Vuetify in a sandbox like CodePen, i.e. what the suggested procedure for that situation is.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76908261/4115031), use the following method:

```
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modularize the file and use ECMA Script 6 or higher syntax:

I don't know about CodePen but at most code runner like Stackoverflow you can have a hack to install script module like this:

```js
// </script><script type="module">

import { createVuetify } from "https://esm.run/vuetify@latest"

console.log(createVuetify)
```

Comment: you can actually use `<script type='module'>` in production because if the browser doesn't support it vue 3 won't support it either